# Port forwarding not working with Test-Kitchen and Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, test-kitchen

I'm on Ubuntu Linux 14.04 and I'm trying to create a Centos VM using kitchen-vagrant. I want port forwarding so that I can forward apache tomcat on my local machine. It's not working though I've specified the port number and private network IPs like in their documentation. On my machine I get "site is unreachable".

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero

platforms:
  - name: centos-6.7
    network:
      - ["forwarded_port", {guest: 8080, host: 8080}]
      - ["private_network", {ip: "192.168.33.33"}]

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[env_rundeck_war::default]
    attributes:
```

When I log into the VM (`kitchen login`), I can access Tomcat on port 8080.

```
jose@jose-desktop $ kitchen login
...
[vagrant@default-centos-67 ~]$ curl -i localhost:8080
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sat, 30 Jul 2016 18:12:23 GMT
```

I have tried moving the network settings under the `driver` section, but that didn't help either. It seems that's how they do it on the [documentation](https://github.com/test-kitchen/kitchen-vagrant#-network).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, `network` is a parameter of the (kitchen-vagrant) `driver`. Thus, the following configuration would be correct:

```
platforms:
  - name: centos-6.7
    driver_config:
      network:
        - ["forwarded_port", {guest: 8080, host: 8080}]
        - ["private_network", {ip: "192.168.33.33"}]
```

You can watch out the contents of the `Vagrantfile` in `.kitchen/kitchen-vagrant/<suite>/` for the following line (to speed up your verification step):

```
c.vm.network(:forwarded_port, {:guest=>8080, :host=>8088})
```

Btw. you don't need a `private_network` if you only want to forward a port (you can omit that line).